# Remove Space Between Body And it's Element's?

Tags: html, css

There is some space between the body and it's elements. How can i remove the Space?
See this image [Image is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6jhl.png)

```css
#rela {position:relative; width:100%; height:500px; clear:both; top:0; right:0; left:0;}
#absol {position:absolute; width:70%; height:400px; clear:left; float:left;}
#absol_2 {position:absolute; width:20%; height:400px; clear:riht; float:right;}
```

```html
<div id='rela' style='background:green;'>

<div id='absol'  style='background:red;'></div>
<div id='absol_2' style='background:purple;' ></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Show us code, rather than image, please.

Comment: have a look now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your css:

```
body{margin:0; padding:0}
```